# Simulating nth in Clojure

Tags: clojure

[The 21st 4clojure problem](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/21#prob-title) asks you to implement `nth`.

However my attempt to implement it:

```
(defn my-nth
  ([s 0] (first s))
  ([s n] (recur s (- n 1))))
```

Leads to the error "   Unsupported binding form: 0"

Could someone explain why that is the error and how to fix it?

Comment: There are languages that do arbitrary pattern matching to route function calls, but Clojure isn't one of them (without some 3rd-party extensions which will fudge what you're looking for). In general, though, you can provide implementations for different *numbers* of arguments, but not ones that match on value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function's arguments, you cannot specify a value, but only symbols. Probably, you borrowed that syntax from Haskell, where you can do that. But not in Clojure.

In your example, the code would be like that:

```
(defn nth-my [coll index not-found] 
  (if (zero? index)
    (if (empty? coll)
      not-found
      (first coll))
    (recur (rest coll) (dec index) not-found)))
```

Usage:

```
user> (nth-my [1 2 3] 0 "dunno")
1
user> (nth-my [1 2 3] 1 "dunno")
2
user> (nth-my [1 2 3] 2 "dunno")
3
user> (nth-my [1 2 3] 4 "dunno")
dunno
```

You are welcome to improve it in the following ways:

- check for negative index; either return `nil` (or default) immediately or start from the end of a collection in reverse order;
- add an additional body when no default was provided (make it `nil` when not passed);
- Probably use loop/recur form to not pass the last default argument every time.